# Como arrastar texto selecionado para a esquerda com sublime text?

Tags: sublime-text

Só consigo achar tutorial que mostra como arrastar pra cima e pra baixo (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>seta</kbd>) ou para a direita (<kbd>TAB</kbd>).

Mas quero selecionar e arrastar tudo de uma vez para a esquerda.

Comment: Não precisa colocar "Resolvido" no título. Sei que é uma prática comum em muitos sites, mas aqui o funcionamento é diferente: basta aceitar a pergunta (o que vc **já fez**, quando clicou no ✓), que a pergunta já é marcada como resolvida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecione o bloco e tente usar as teclas combinadas dessa maneira: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.